# Why? Div which contains other divs is working only while I declare same class and id together in css

Tags: html, css

I made simple div which contains other divs, and when I set its size and background in class nothing happened, same thing when I set it on id, but when I set same class and id, it worked. Why?
html

css

```
.baza{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 900px;
    background-color: grey;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: dotted;
 }
#baza {
width: 1000px;
height: 900px;
background-color: grey;
margin-left: auto;
margin-right: auto;
border-width: 1px;
border-style: dotted;
}
.baner {
height: 150px;

}
```

html

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html>
    <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link rel="Stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
    </head>
    <body>
    <div class="baza" id="baza">
    <div class="baner">


    </div>

    <div class="pasek">
        <marquee><i> Strona internetowa koła fizycznego</i></marquee>


    </div>
    <div class="menu">
        <ul>
         <li> Strona główna</li>
         <li>Terminy spotkań</li>
         <li> Kontakt</li>

        </ul>

    </div>
    <div class="tresc">

    </div>
    <div class="stopka">

    </div>


    </div>
    </body>
    <footer>
    </footer>
    </html>
```

Comment: I can't see your code

Comment: Please add your html and css code :)

Comment: Done, sorry about that

Comment: working https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/L3nkg5zt/

Comment: HTML is incomplete, there's a closing tag of a div at the very top and there is neither a `#baza` nor is there a `.baza`  or `.baner`. Ok, further edits now completed.

Comment: Okay I noticed that the problem was in " @charset "utf-8" " on css file begining

Answer (score 2):

The code works as it should:

Using class name only: [**JS Fiddle 1**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/L3nkg5zt/)

```css
.baza{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 900px;
    background-color: grey;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: dotted;
}
```

```html
<div class="baza">
  <div class="baner">
  </div>
  <div class="pasek">
    <marquee><i> Strona internetowa koła fizycznego</i></marquee>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li> Strona główna</li>
      <li>Terminy spotkań</li>
      <li> Kontakt</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="tresc">
  </div>
  <div class="stopka">
  </div>
</div>
```

---

Using id only: [**JS Fiddle 2**](https://jsfiddle.net/Mi_Creativity/L3nkg5zt/1/)

```css
#baza{
    width: 1000px;
    height: 900px;
    background-color: grey;
    margin-left: auto;
    margin-right: auto;
    border-width: 1px;
    border-style: dotted;
}
```

```html
<div id="baza">
  <div class="baner">
  </div>
  <div class="pasek">
    <marquee><i> Strona internetowa koła fizycznego</i></marquee>
  </div>
  <div class="menu">
    <ul>
      <li> Strona główna</li>
      <li>Terminy spotkań</li>
      <li> Kontakt</li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="tresc">
  </div>
  <div class="stopka">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Here a simple `div` which contains other `divs`. No problem here with the CSS class or id. Check out this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ancxaf1d/1/).

HTML

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="first">
    Hello World!
  </div>
  <div id="second">
   The pink champagne on ice
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.container {width: 300px; height: 60px; background-color: grey; padding: 8px; }
.first {background-color: #d1d1d1;}
#second {color: #fff;}
```

Try to post your code.

**UPDATE**

Your code works correctly [here](https://jsfiddle.net/ancxaf1d/2/).

Comment: Look at the second fiddle... there it works... you don't need to specify both (id and class)

Comment: Please add working code in your answer and not as a url only.

Answer (score 0):

the problem that no thing happen it means the CSS and html not working together since we know its connected right . so the problem one of the following

**problem in the CSS**

1. missing `;` or `}`
2. the properties is over written by other selectors

**problem in the html**

1. the `</div>` tags not closed properly
2. problem in the name ( capital small lettters )

**one last note**

in your code

```
    .baza{
        width: 1000px;
        height: 900px;
        background-color: grey;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-style: dotted;
     }
    #baza {
        width: 1000px;
        height: 900px;
        background-color: grey;
        margin-left: auto;
        margin-right: auto;
        border-width: 1px;
        border-style: dotted;
    }
```

this is not use class and ID ... the ID come after the class so it will override it ...

so your issue is one of the points I mentioned  before